# I want to get two side by side horizontal lines as shown in the figure

Tags: formatting

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
I want them on the same row, side by side. 

\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{0.45\textwidth}@{}}
\toprule
Supervisor\\
Name of the Supervisor\\
Title, Affiliation\\
Head of Department\\
Department of Electronics and Computer Engineering\\
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{0.45\textwidth}@{}}
\toprule
Internal Examiner\\
Name of Internal Examiner\\
Title, Affiliation\\
\end{tabular}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{0.45\textwidth}@{}}
\toprule
Supervisor\\
Name of the Supervisor\\
Title, Affiliation\\
Head of Department\\
Department of Electronics and Computer Engineering\\
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{0.45\textwidth}@{}}
\toprule
Internal Examiner\\
Name of Internal Examiner\\
Title, Affiliation\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use two `tabulars`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\begin{document}
I want them on the same row, side by side.

\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.45\textwidth}@{}}
\toprule
Supervisor\\
Name of the Supervisor\\
Title, Affiliation\\
Head of Department\\
Department of Electronics and Computer Engineering\\
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.45\textwidth}@{}}
\toprule
Internal Examiner\\
Name of Internal Examiner\\
Title, Affiliation\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have used `booktabs` for `\toprule` so that the line can be customised (for example, `\toprule[1pt]` for 1pt thick rule). If you don't need that, use `\hline` without `booktabs`.

To add more stuff, you have to leave an empty line (amount to a new paragraph).

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
I want them on the same row, side by side.

\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{0.45\textwidth}@{}}
\toprule
Supervisor\\
Name of the Supervisor\\
Title, Affiliation\\
Head of Department\\
Department of Electronics and Computer Engineering\\
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{0.45\textwidth}@{}}
\toprule
Internal Examiner\\
Name of Internal Examiner\\
Title, Affiliation\\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{0.45\textwidth}@{}}
\toprule
Supervisor\\
Name of the Supervisor\\
Title, Affiliation\\
Head of Department\\
Department of Electronics and Computer Engineering\\
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{0.45\textwidth}@{}}
\toprule
Internal Examiner\\
Name of Internal Examiner\\
Title, Affiliation\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would need to start new tabular if I want to add extra stuff or I could just put them inside each tabular with new \toprule?

Comment: I have other rows too. I ditto copied the code for other rows but they are not aligned with the above row.

Comment: I have added them now.

Answer (score 1):

Or, use of two `minipage` will do too.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
I want them on the same row, side by side. 
\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\line(1,0){150}\\
Supervisor\\
Name of the Supervisor\\
Title, Affiliation\\
Head of Department\\
Department of Electronics \\ and Computer Engineering\\
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\line(1,0){150}\\
Internal Examiner\\
Name of Internal Examiner\\
Title, Affiliation\\    
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\line(1,0){150}\\
Supervisor\\
Name of the Supervisor\\
Title, Affiliation\\
Head of Department\\
Department of Electronics \\ and Computer Engineering\\
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\line(1,0){150}\\
Internal Examiner\\
Name of Internal Examiner\\
Title, Affiliation\\    
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about the spacing between the rows?

Comment: Use of [2ex] or [<length>] right after \\